# Which of following sql instructions do not is Standard SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
a)  GRANT
b)  SELECT
c)  CREATE
d)  All previous is sql standard
```

If you can share with me a link for learning all standard sql, i would appreciate

Comment: The proper link should be https://www.google.com

Comment: They all come in ANSI SQL, but different products have different additions/restrictions.

Comment: yes, but only need for standar sql sintax example: CAST AND CONVERT, cast is sql standar convert no

Comment: Read the documentation for the product you're using. If your product doesn't support cast, you'll have to use convert

Comment: This question pretty much covers it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714461/ansi-sql-manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is d. But google is ideal platform for this kind of query or go to https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp