# How do I join two dataframes, based on conditions, with no common variable?

Tags: sql, r, sas, inner-join, sqldf

I am trying to recreate the following SAS code in R

```sql
PROC SQL;
    create table counts_2018 as 
    select a.*, b.cell_no 
    from work.universe201808 a, work.selpar17 b 
    where a.newregionxx = b.lower_region2 
      and a.froempment >= b.lower_size 
      and a.froempment <= b.upper_size 
      and a.frosic07_2 >= b.lower_class2 
      and a.frosic07_2 <= b.upper_class2;
QUIT;
```

What this does, in effect, is assign the *cell_no* found in *selpar17* to the data in *universe201808*, based on the fulfillment of **all 6 conditions** outlined in the code. Data which does not fulfill these conditions, and thus won't have a *cell_no* assigned to it, is not included in the final table.

The documentation/answers I have found so far all start with a step where the two dataframes are merged by a common variable, then an `sqldf` `select` is carried out. I do not have a common column, and thus I cannot merge my dataframes.

Comment: You should be able to just put that query into `sqldf` with minimal changes. Remove the `work.` parts, the `proc sql;` and `;quit;`, and start the query with `select ...`. So, have you tried that? Was there an error, and if so, what was it?

Comment: Are you able to provide me the first line of code with the selecting of two dataframes? The documentation I can find only shows an argument for one dataframe

Comment: It accepts normal SQL queries like proc sql, `counts_2018 <- sqldf('select a.*, b.cell_no from universe201808 
a, selpar17 b where 
a.newregionxx = b.lower_region2 and 
a.froempment >= b.lower_size and a.froempment <= b.upper_size and 
a.frosic07_2 >= b.lower_class2 and a.frosic07_2 <= b.upper_class2')` should work.

Comment: Ah i was missing the ' ' . the only issue is "  Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  near "where": syntax error  "

Comment: Ok, you'll have to share your data then, otherwise no one can reproduce the problem.

Comment: The `sqldf` readme page has a lot of good examples of queries involving joins. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/README.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you are running an implicit join between the two tables which is not advised in SQL. Per ANSI-1992 (a 25+ year specification) that made the explicit `JOIN` the standard way of joining relations, consider revising your SQL query accordingly.

Contrary to your statement, you in fact *do* have a common column between the tables as shown in your equality condition: `a.newregionxx = b.lower_region2` which can serve as the `JOIN` condition. Even use the `BETWEEN` operator for concision:

```
new_df <- sqldf('select u.*, s.cell_no 
                 from universe201808 u
                 inner join selpar17 s 
                         on u.newregionxx = s.lower_region2 
                 where u.froempment between s.lower_size and s.upper_size 
                   and u.frosic07_2 between s.lower_class2 and s.upper_class2')
```

In fact, you can remove the `where` altogether and place all in the `on` clause:

```
...
on u.newregionxx = s.lower_region2 
and u.froempment between s.lower_size and s.upper_size 
and u.frosic07_2 between s.lower_class2 and s.upper_class2
```

Comment: What is the name of this ANSI specification? I would like to look into this further.

Comment: The industry routinely updates ANSI specifications of the SQL language, notably 1992, 1999, 2003, 2008, etc. See this answer for links on actual [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1714461/1422451). Most RDBMS's adhere to 1992.